# Replacing unicode linebreaks with BR

Tags: ruby, unicode, line-breaks

In my XML files, there are unicode line breaks like shown in this screenshot.
Use this link to see the screenshot

[bigger screenshot](http://www.polyvision.org/hex.png)

The two dots after "minds." is the line break. I've googled and tried almost everything I know to replace them with ruby (1.8) but without any luck.

Here's my code (with different tries of unicodes), maybe someone could help me.

```
def formatedBody
  t = self.body.gsub("\u000a","<br/>")
  t = t.gsub("\u000d","<br/>")
  t = t.gsub("\u0009","<br/>")
  t = t.gsub("\u000c","<br/>")
  t = t.gsub("\u0085","<br/>")
  t = t.gsub("\u2028","<br/>")
  t = t.gsub("\u2029","<br/>")
  t = t.gsub(/0A\0A/u,"<br/>")
  return t
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two `0x0A` values are the hex representation of line-feeds. Regular ol' ASCII line feeds, AKA `"\n\n"` in a string.

So, `t = t.gsub(/\n/, "<br/>")` should work.

```
t = "foo\u000d\u0009\u000c\u0085\u2028\u2029\nbar"
p t

t = t.gsub(/\u000d|\u0009|\u000c|\u0085|\u2028|\u2029|\n/,"<br/>")
puts t
```

You can replace the list of OR'd characters with:

```
t = t.gsub(/[\u000d\u0009\u000c\u0085\u2028\u2029\n]/,"<br/>")
```

Either way, the output would look like:

```
"foo\r\t\f\u2028\u2029\nbar"
foo<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>bar
```

The reason your

```
t = t.gsub(/0A\0A/u,"<br/>")
```

doesn't work is the regex is not correct.

```
t = t.gsub(/\x0A/,"<br/>")
```

is an alternate way of defining:

```
t = t.gsub(/\n/,"<br/>")
```

Comment: thanx man ! you saved my hair ;) The OR'd solutiuon works like a charm !

Comment: @ghostrifle glad it helped. Remember to come back and select this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (using ruby 1.8.7) and I simply solve it with:

```
t = t.gsub(/\xE2\x80(?:\xA8|\xA9)/, '<br/>')
```